How to include and ignore a variable in a r function?
I am confused about how to make a representative title for my question, but I hope the details below can be understood.
I want to create a function to include or ignore a variable.
My data consists of column for group of data, i.e. high and low. I can create a function to obtain descriptive statistics for either high or low group, as follows:
desc <- function(df, group){
  library(dplyr)
  data <- df%>% filter(level == group) %>% 
    select(CK, PK, PCK, TK, TCK, TPK, TPCK, TPACK) %>% 
    psych::describe(quant=c(.25,.75)) %>%
    as_tibble(rownames="rowname")
  data.summary <- data %>%
    select(var=rowname, n, min, q25=Q0.25, median, q75=Q0.75, max, mean, sd) %>%
    print()
}

How can I also include both groups (or ignore the group at all)? I am not proficienct in creating a function yet, so I am stuck on how I can approach this.
This is my data:
structure(list(CK = c(4.5, 5, 3.75, 4, 4.25, 5, 3.5, 4.25, 4.5, 
3, 2.75, 4.5, 4.75, 4.25, 4.5, 3.75, 4, 4, 3.75, 3.25, 3.5, 3.25, 
4.75, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4.75, 4.25, 2.75, 4.75, 4.5, 5, 3.25, 4, 5, 
4, 4.25, 4, 3.5, 4.25, 5, 5, 4, 3.75, 4, 3.75, 3.75, 4, 4.75, 
5, 4.5, 3.75, 3.25, 4.5, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 4, 3.75, 5, 3.5, 4, 4.25, 
3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 3.75, 4, 3.5, 5, 3.25, 3.75, 3.75, 4, 3.75, 
3.25, 3.25, 4.75, 3.5, 3.25, 4, 2.75, 3, 4, 4.5, 3.75, 4.75, 
4, 3.75, 4.25, 3.75, 3.5, 3.25, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 3.5, 4, 3, 4, 
4, 2.75, 4, 4, 4.5, 4.75, 4, 3, 4.5, 4, 4.75, 3.75, 4.5, 2.5, 
3.5, 2.75, 3.75, 4, 3.75, 4.25, 3.75, 4, 4.5, 2.75, 3.5, 4.25, 
3.5, 4, 3.75, 2.75, 3, 4.75, 3.75, 4.5, 4.5, 4, 3.75, 4.75, 3, 
4.25, 3.75, 3, 5, 3.75, 4, 3.5, 3.75, 4.75, 3.75, 4, 4.5, 5, 
4.75, 4.25, 4.75, 3.75, 3.25, 4, 4, 3.5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4.25, 4, 
3.75, 4, 4.75, 3.5, 3.25, 4, 3.75, 3, 3.75, 4.25, 4, 3, 3.5, 
3, 3.5, 3.75, 4, 4.25, 3, 4.25, 4.25, 4, 3.75, 3.25, 2, 4, 5, 
4, 3.25, 4, 3.25, 3.75, 3.5, 3, 2.75, 5, 3.75, 3.75, 4.25, 4, 
4.5, 3.5, 3.75, 4.5, 3.25, 3.25), PK = c(4, 4, 4.28571428571429, 
3.85714285714286, 4.14285714285714, 4.42857142857143, 3.14285714285714, 
3.71428571428571, 3.71428571428571, 3.57142857142857, 4.57142857142857, 
4, 3.42857142857143, 3.71428571428571, 4.28571428571429, 4, 4.57142857142857, 
4.57142857142857, 3, 3.71428571428571, 3.14285714285714, 4.57142857142857, 
5, 3.85714285714286, 4.42857142857143, 4, 4, 5, 4.42857142857143, 
4.42857142857143, 5, 4.28571428571429, 4.57142857142857, 3.28571428571429, 
4, 5, 4, 4.85714285714286, 2.85714285714286, 3.14285714285714, 
4, 4.71428571428571, 4.85714285714286, 5, 3.85714285714286, 3.42857142857143, 
4.71428571428571, 3.57142857142857, 5, 4.85714285714286, 4.42857142857143, 
4.71428571428571, 3.71428571428571, 3.85714285714286, 4, 3.71428571428571, 
4.57142857142857, 4.14285714285714, 4.28571428571429, 2.71428571428571, 
5, 3.42857142857143, 3.57142857142857, 4.71428571428571, 3.42857142857143, 
4, 3.71428571428571, 3.57142857142857, 4.14285714285714, 3.71428571428571, 
5, 3.57142857142857, 3.57142857142857, 3.71428571428571, 4.14285714285714, 
4.28571428571429, 3.71428571428571, 3.28571428571429, 4.85714285714286, 
4.57142857142857, 4, 4, 3.85714285714286, 3, 3.28571428571429, 
4.42857142857143, 4, 4, 4.42857142857143, 3.71428571428571, 4.85714285714286, 
4, 3, 4.57142857142857, 3.28571428571429, 5, 5, 4.28571428571429, 
5, 4.42857142857143, 3.85714285714286, 2.71428571428571, 4.28571428571429, 
5, 3.57142857142857, 4.85714285714286, 3.71428571428571, 4.42857142857143, 
4, 4, 3.57142857142857, 3.57142857142857, 4, 4.14285714285714, 
3.28571428571429, 4.14285714285714, 2.57142857142857, 3.85714285714286, 
3, 3.71428571428571, 3.71428571428571, 4.85714285714286, 4.14285714285714, 
3.85714285714286, 3.28571428571429, 4.14285714285714, 3.28571428571429, 
3.85714285714286, 3.57142857142857, 3.85714285714286, 3.71428571428571, 
3.28571428571429, 3.28571428571429, 3.57142857142857, 4.57142857142857, 
4, 4.85714285714286, 3.71428571428571, 4, 3.57142857142857, 3.85714285714286, 
3.14285714285714, 4.42857142857143, 4, 2.85714285714286, 5, 3.57142857142857, 
4, 3.14285714285714, 3, 5, 4.57142857142857, 4.42857142857143, 
5, 4.71428571428571, 4.14285714285714, 4.14285714285714, 4.28571428571429, 
4.28571428571429, 3.71428571428571, 4.28571428571429, 4, 3.57142857142857, 
4.85714285714286, 4.71428571428571, 5, 3.85714285714286, 4.85714285714286, 
4, 4.85714285714286, 4, 4, 3.28571428571429, 4, 4, 3.85714285714286, 
3.71428571428571, 3.42857142857143, 3.42857142857143, 4.42857142857143, 
3.85714285714286, 3.14285714285714, 3, 3.57142857142857, 3.42857142857143, 
3.57142857142857, 4.57142857142857, 3, 5, 3.85714285714286, 4, 
4, 3.71428571428571, 2, 4, 5, 4.28571428571429, 4, 3.85714285714286, 
3.85714285714286, 4.28571428571429, 4.14285714285714, 3.42857142857143, 
4, 4.28571428571429, 4.14285714285714, 4.28571428571429, 4.57142857142857, 
3.71428571428571, 3.57142857142857, 4.14285714285714, 3.71428571428571, 
5, 3.28571428571429, 3.57142857142857), PCK = c(4.25, 3.75, 4.25, 
3.75, 4.75, 4.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.5, 3.5, 4.25, 4.25, 3.25, 3.75, 
4, 3.5, 4.25, 3.75, 3.25, 3.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.25, 4.25, 4.25, 4, 
4, 5, 3.75, 3.75, 5, 4.5, 4.5, 4, 4.75, 4.5, 4, 4, 3.75, 3, 3.75, 
4.75, 4.25, 4.75, 3.5, 4, 4.75, 4, 5, 4.75, 4.5, 4.75, 3.75, 
3.75, 4.25, 4, 4.5, 4, 4.5, 3, 4.75, 3.5, 4, 4.25, 3.5, 4, 4, 
3.25, 4.25, 3.5, 5, 3, 4, 3.75, 4.5, 4, 4.25, 3.75, 4.75, 3.75, 
4, 4, 4, 3.25, 3.5, 4.25, 4, 3.75, 4, 3.25, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 
5, 4.25, 4.75, 3.5, 3, 3, 4.75, 5, 2.75, 4.25, 3.25, 3.75, 3.75, 
4, 3.75, 4, 4.25, 4, 3.25, 4, 2.5, 4, 3.5, 3.5, 3.25, 4.5, 3.75, 
4, 3.5, 4.5, 3.5, 3.25, 3.5, 4, 3.5, 3.5, 3, 3.5, 3.75, 4, 4.75, 
3.25, 3.75, 4, 4.25, 3, 4, 4, 3.25, 4.75, 3.5, 4.5, 3, 3.75, 
4.75, 4.75, 5, 4.75, 5, 3.5, 3.75, 4.25, 4.5, 3, 4, 3.75, 3.5, 
4.75, 4.75, 4.25, 3.5, 4.25, 4, 4.25, 4, 4, 3.5, 3.25, 3.75, 
4, 3.75, 3.5, 4.25, 4, 3.5, 3, 3.25, 3.75, 4, 4, 4.5, 3, 5, 4, 
4, 4.25, 3.75, 3, 3.75, 5, 4.5, 4.25, 4.75, 4, 4.75, 4.25, 3.25, 
3.75, 4.25, 4.25, 4, 3.75, 4, 4.5, 4.25, 4, 4.5, 2.75, 4.25), 
    TK = c(4, 5, 4.83333333333333, 4, 5, 4.83333333333333, 4, 
    4.83333333333333, 4, 4.16666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 
    5, 4.66666666666667, 5, 4.83333333333333, 4, 4.33333333333333, 
    4.5, 4.5, 4.83333333333333, 3.5, 4.5, 5, 4.83333333333333, 
    5, 5, 4, 5, 4.16666666666667, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4.16666666666667, 
    5, 5, 4.66666666666667, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4.33333333333333, 5, 
    4.66666666666667, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3.5, 5, 4, 4.83333333333333, 
    4.83333333333333, 5, 4.66666666666667, 4.16666666666667, 
    5, 3.5, 5, 4, 4.66666666666667, 4.83333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 
    4.66666666666667, 4.83333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 
    4, 4.66666666666667, 3.33333333333333, 4, 3.83333333333333, 
    5, 4.83333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 3, 5, 4.5, 4.66666666666667, 
    4, 4.33333333333333, 4, 3.5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4.33333333333333, 
    4, 3.66666666666667, 4, 3.5, 4.66666666666667, 5, 4.66666666666667, 
    4.83333333333333, 4, 3, 3.33333333333333, 4.5, 5, 3.33333333333333, 
    5, 4.83333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 5, 5, 3.5, 5, 4, 5, 
    4, 4, 2.33333333333333, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3.66666666666667, 5, 
    5, 4, 4.83333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 4, 4.66666666666667, 
    5, 4, 3.83333333333333, 3, 3.83333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 
    4, 5, 4.83333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 5, 5, 5, 4.83333333333333, 
    4, 2.66666666666667, 5, 4, 4.66666666666667, 3.83333333333333, 
    5, 4.83333333333333, 4, 4.5, 5, 5, 4.66666666666667, 5, 5, 
    4.83333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 4, 
    4.5, 4.66666666666667, 5, 5, 4.66666666666667, 4, 4.66666666666667, 
    4, 4.83333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 4.16666666666667, 
    3.66666666666667, 5, 4, 5, 4.66666666666667, 5, 4.5, 4, 3.83333333333333, 
    4, 4.66666666666667, 5, 5, 5, 3.83333333333333, 5, 4, 4, 
    4.5, 3.66666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 4.5, 5, 4.16666666666667, 
    5, 5, 5, 4.16666666666667, 4.33333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 
    5, 5, 3.66666666666667, 5, 5, 4, 4.5, 5, 4, 5, 4.83333333333333, 
    4.83333333333333), TCK = c(4.42857142857143, 3.42857142857143, 
    4.85714285714286, 4, 4.57142857142857, 4, 4, 4.42857142857143, 
    3.57142857142857, 3.71428571428571, 4.42857142857143, 4.14285714285714, 
    4, 4.71428571428571, 4, 3.57142857142857, 4.28571428571429, 
    3.57142857142857, 3.14285714285714, 4.28571428571429, 3, 
    4.14285714285714, 4.14285714285714, 4.85714285714286, 4, 
    4.85714285714286, 4, 5, 3.28571428571429, 4.14285714285714, 
    4.71428571428571, 4.28571428571429, 5, 5, 4, 4.85714285714286, 
    4, 4.57142857142857, 3.57142857142857, 3.28571428571429, 
    3.85714285714286, 5, 4.42857142857143, 3.71428571428571, 
    3.71428571428571, 4.42857142857143, 5, 4, 5, 4.85714285714286, 
    2.28571428571429, 4.71428571428571, 3.14285714285714, 3.28571428571429, 
    5, 3.71428571428571, 4, 4, 4.71428571428571, 3, 5, 3.28571428571429, 
    4, 4.28571428571429, 3, 3.42857142857143, 4.28571428571429, 
    3.57142857142857, 3.28571428571429, 4, 4.71428571428571, 
    4.28571428571429, 3.57142857142857, 3.57142857142857, 4.14285714285714, 
    3.71428571428571, 3.85714285714286, 3, 4.71428571428571, 
    4.42857142857143, 4.28571428571429, 3.85714285714286, 3.85714285714286, 
    3.14285714285714, 3.71428571428571, 4.71428571428571, 4, 
    5, 4.28571428571429, 4, 4.71428571428571, 4, 2.85714285714286, 
    4, 3.71428571428571, 5, 5, 4.14285714285714, 5, 3.57142857142857, 
    3.42857142857143, 2.57142857142857, 4.28571428571429, 4.28571428571429, 
    3, 4.85714285714286, 4.28571428571429, 5, 3, 5, 3.57142857142857, 
    4.57142857142857, 4, 4, 3.57142857142857, 4.28571428571429, 
    2.42857142857143, 4, 3.42857142857143, 3.71428571428571, 
    3.71428571428571, 4.14285714285714, 4.71428571428571, 5, 
    3.42857142857143, 4.71428571428571, 3.57142857142857, 4, 
    4, 4, 3.71428571428571, 3.57142857142857, 3, 3, 4.85714285714286, 
    4, 4.57142857142857, 3.85714285714286, 3.42857142857143, 
    5, 4.14285714285714, 4, 4.57142857142857, 4, 2.57142857142857, 
    5, 4, 4.28571428571429, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4.85714285714286, 
    5, 3.71428571428571, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4.57142857142857, 4, 3.28571428571429, 
    5, 5, 5, 3.85714285714286, 3.71428571428571, 4.42857142857143, 
    4, 4, 4.14285714285714, 3.42857142857143, 3.71428571428571, 
    4.85714285714286, 3.71428571428571, 5, 4.57142857142857, 
    4.71428571428571, 4.14285714285714, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3.71428571428571, 
    3.85714285714286, 4.57142857142857, 4.42857142857143, 5, 
    4, 4, 3.42857142857143, 4, 2, 4.42857142857143, 4.57142857142857, 
    4, 4.85714285714286, 4, 4, 4, 4.14285714285714, 3, 4.71428571428571, 
    4, 4.28571428571429, 4.71428571428571, 4.57142857142857, 
    4, 4, 4.14285714285714, 3.57142857142857, 5, 3.14285714285714, 
    4.71428571428571), TPK = c(4.57142857142857, 4, 4, 3.85714285714286, 
    4.71428571428571, 4.14285714285714, 4, 3.14285714285714, 
    3.28571428571429, 3.71428571428571, 4, 4.85714285714286, 
    3, 4.42857142857143, 4, 3.71428571428571, 4.28571428571429, 
    3.71428571428571, 2.57142857142857, 3.14285714285714, 2.57142857142857, 
    4.28571428571429, 4, 4, 4.71428571428571, 4, 4, 5, 3.42857142857143, 
    4, 5, 3.85714285714286, 4.85714285714286, 4.57142857142857, 
    4, 4.85714285714286, 4, 4.28571428571429, 3.28571428571429, 
    3, 3.71428571428571, 4.85714285714286, 4.85714285714286, 
    3.28571428571429, 3.57142857142857, 4.42857142857143, 4.42857142857143, 
    3.71428571428571, 5, 5, 3.28571428571429, 5, 3.42857142857143, 
    3.57142857142857, 3.71428571428571, 4.28571428571429, 4.42857142857143, 
    4, 4.57142857142857, 2.85714285714286, 5, 3.14285714285714, 
    3.85714285714286, 3.71428571428571, 3, 4, 4.71428571428571, 
    3.14285714285714, 3.57142857142857, 3.42857142857143, 4.85714285714286, 
    3.57142857142857, 3.14285714285714, 4, 4, 3.71428571428571, 
    4, 3.71428571428571, 4, 4.71428571428571, 4.42857142857143, 
    4, 4, 3.28571428571429, 3.14285714285714, 4.57142857142857, 
    4, 4, 4.14285714285714, 4, 4.71428571428571, 4, 3, 4, 4, 
    5, 5, 4.42857142857143, 4.57142857142857, 3.71428571428571, 
    3.28571428571429, 2, 4.57142857142857, 5, 3, 5, 3, 4.28571428571429, 
    3.71428571428571, 5, 4, 4.57142857142857, 4, 4, 3.71428571428571, 
    4.85714285714286, 2.42857142857143, 4, 2.57142857142857, 
    3.71428571428571, 3.42857142857143, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4.71428571428571, 
    3.28571428571429, 4, 4, 3.85714285714286, 3.14285714285714, 
    3.28571428571429, 3, 3.57142857142857, 4.28571428571429, 
    4, 5, 3.57142857142857, 3.85714285714286, 4.85714285714286, 
    4.28571428571429, 3.42857142857143, 4, 4, 3.42857142857143, 
    5, 4, 4, 3.85714285714286, 3.85714285714286, 5, 3.85714285714286, 
    4.14285714285714, 4.57142857142857, 5, 4.57142857142857, 
    4.57142857142857, 4.71428571428571, 3.57142857142857, 4.42857142857143, 
    4, 4, 3.57142857142857, 4.85714285714286, 4.14285714285714, 
    5, 3.42857142857143, 4, 4.14285714285714, 4, 4, 3.85714285714286, 
    3.28571428571429, 3.57142857142857, 4.28571428571429, 3.71428571428571, 
    4.85714285714286, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3.28571428571429, 4, 3.85714285714286, 
    3.71428571428571, 3.85714285714286, 4.71428571428571, 4.14285714285714, 
    4.85714285714286, 4, 4, 3.57142857142857, 3.14285714285714, 
    2.42857142857143, 3.14285714285714, 5, 4.71428571428571, 
    3.85714285714286, 4.57142857142857, 4.85714285714286, 4.28571428571429, 
    3.85714285714286, 3.85714285714286, 4.57142857142857, 4, 
    4, 4.85714285714286, 4.71428571428571, 4, 4.57142857142857, 
    4.28571428571429, 4, 4.71428571428571, 3, 3.85714285714286
    ), TPCK = c(4.71428571428571, 3.71428571428571, 4, 4, 4.71428571428571, 
    3.85714285714286, 3, 3.14285714285714, 3.57142857142857, 
    4, 4, 4.71428571428571, 3.71428571428571, 4.14285714285714, 
    4.42857142857143, 3.85714285714286, 4.28571428571429, 3.28571428571429, 
    3, 3.14285714285714, 2, 4.14285714285714, 3.85714285714286, 
    3.85714285714286, 4, 4, 4, 5, 2.71428571428571, 4, 5, 4.14285714285714, 
    5, 4.71428571428571, 3.71428571428571, 4.71428571428571, 
    3.85714285714286, 4.57142857142857, 3.71428571428571, 3, 
    4, 4.42857142857143, 5, 3, 3.57142857142857, 3.71428571428571, 
    3, 3.85714285714286, 5, 4.85714285714286, 2, 4.71428571428571, 
    3.57142857142857, 3.28571428571429, 4.14285714285714, 4.14285714285714, 
    4.14285714285714, 4.14285714285714, 4.57142857142857, 2.85714285714286, 
    5, 3.28571428571429, 4, 4, 3, 3.85714285714286, 4, 3.14285714285714, 
    3, 3.42857142857143, 5, 3.71428571428571, 4, 3.85714285714286, 
    3.85714285714286, 3.85714285714286, 3.57142857142857, 4, 
    4, 4.42857142857143, 3.85714285714286, 3.71428571428571, 
    3.57142857142857, 3, 3, 4.14285714285714, 4, 4.14285714285714, 
    4, 4, 4.71428571428571, 4, 3, 4, 3.85714285714286, 5, 5, 
    4.14285714285714, 4.85714285714286, 3.42857142857143, 3.42857142857143, 
    2.42857142857143, 4, 4.42857142857143, 3, 4.85714285714286, 
    3.57142857142857, 4.14285714285714, 4.57142857142857, 5, 
    3.85714285714286, 4, 3.71428571428571, 4, 3.57142857142857, 
    4.28571428571429, 2.71428571428571, 4, 2.85714285714286, 
    3.42857142857143, 3.71428571428571, 3.57142857142857, 4, 
    5, 3.57142857142857, 4.57142857142857, 3.28571428571429, 
    4, 3.71428571428571, 3.14285714285714, 3.14285714285714, 
    3.57142857142857, 3, 4, 4.57142857142857, 3.85714285714286, 
    4.71428571428571, 3.57142857142857, 4, 4.85714285714286, 
    3.28571428571429, 2.42857142857143, 4.71428571428571, 3.85714285714286, 
    2.28571428571429, 5, 3.85714285714286, 4, 3, 3.57142857142857, 
    4.14285714285714, 3.42857142857143, 4.85714285714286, 4.85714285714286, 
    4.14285714285714, 3.71428571428571, 4.14285714285714, 4.42857142857143, 
    2.28571428571429, 4.14285714285714, 4, 3.28571428571429, 
    3.42857142857143, 4.85714285714286, 3.85714285714286, 4.71428571428571, 
    3.85714285714286, 3.85714285714286, 4.14285714285714, 4, 
    4, 4, 3.42857142857143, 3.57142857142857, 3.85714285714286, 
    4, 4.71428571428571, 3, 4.14285714285714, 4.57142857142857, 
    4, 4, 3.57142857142857, 3.71428571428571, 3.42857142857143, 
    3.57142857142857, 4.42857142857143, 4, 4.28571428571429, 
    4, 4, 3, 2.85714285714286, 1.14285714285714, 3.57142857142857, 
    5, 5, 4.57142857142857, 4.71428571428571, 4.71428571428571, 
    4.28571428571429, 4.14285714285714, 3.57142857142857, 4.28571428571429, 
    4, 3.85714285714286, 4.14285714285714, 4.57142857142857, 
    4, 4.42857142857143, 4.14285714285714, 3.42857142857143, 
    5, 2.85714285714286, 3.57142857142857), TPACK = c(4.35714285714286, 
    4.07142857142857, 4.30952380952381, 3.92857142857143, 4.5952380952381, 
    4.30952380952381, 3.57142857142857, 3.80952380952381, 3.69047619047619, 
    3.71428571428571, 4.16666666666667, 4.5, 3.78571428571429, 
    4.30952380952381, 4.28571428571429, 3.78571428571429, 4.30952380952381, 
    3.9047619047619, 3.26190476190476, 3.71428571428571, 2.85714285714286, 
    4.14285714285714, 4.4047619047619, 4.23809523809524, 4.35714285714286, 
    4.28571428571429, 4, 4.97619047619048, 3.66666666666667, 
    4.0952380952381, 4.92857142857143, 4.33333333333333, 4.85714285714286, 
    4.33333333333333, 4.04761904761905, 4.85714285714286, 4.11904761904762, 
    4.5, 3.69047619047619, 3.11904761904762, 3.92857142857143, 
    4.80952380952381, 4.69047619047619, 4.04761904761905, 3.80952380952381, 
    4.14285714285714, 4.38095238095238, 3.83333333333333, 4.9047619047619, 
    4.88095238095238, 3.4047619047619, 4.78571428571429, 3.5952380952381, 
    3.69047619047619, 4.33333333333333, 4.07142857142857, 4.33333333333333, 
    4.11904761904762, 4.54761904761905, 3.04761904761905, 4.97619047619048, 
    3.42857142857143, 4, 4.28571428571429, 3.23809523809524, 
    3.92857142857143, 4.21428571428571, 3.45238095238095, 3.80952380952381, 
    3.66666666666667, 4.88095238095238, 3.5952380952381, 3.69047619047619, 
    3.78571428571429, 4.21428571428571, 4.02380952380952, 3.85714285714286, 
    3.42857142857143, 4.54761904761905, 4.35714285714286, 4.11904761904762, 
    3.92857142857143, 3.80952380952381, 3.23809523809524, 3.4047619047619, 
    4.52380952380952, 3.97619047619048, 4.38095238095238, 4.14285714285714, 
    3.85714285714286, 4.66666666666667, 3.97619047619048, 3.11904761904762, 
    4.02380952380952, 3.54761904761905, 4.95238095238095, 4.9047619047619, 
    4.28571428571429, 4.85714285714286, 3.76190476190476, 3.42857142857143, 
    2.66666666666667, 4.33333333333333, 4.69047619047619, 3.0952380952381, 
    4.76190476190476, 3.80952380952381, 4.45238095238095, 4.07142857142857, 
    4.64285714285714, 3.64285714285714, 4.30952380952381, 3.97619047619048, 
    4.23809523809524, 3.5952380952381, 4.30952380952381, 2.5, 
    3.92857142857143, 3.14285714285714, 3.83333333333333, 3.69047619047619, 
    4.07142857142857, 4.28571428571429, 4.5952380952381, 3.5, 
    4.57142857142857, 3.5, 3.85714285714286, 3.95238095238095, 
    3.9047619047619, 3.57142857142857, 3.52380952380952, 3.02380952380952, 
    3.52380952380952, 4.54761904761905, 3.95238095238095, 4.78571428571429, 
    3.88095238095238, 3.80952380952381, 4.5, 4.16666666666667, 
    3.45238095238095, 4.42857142857143, 3.95238095238095, 2.83333333333333, 
    4.97619047619048, 3.83333333333333, 4.19047619047619, 3.5, 
    3.83333333333333, 4.78571428571429, 3.85714285714286, 4.4047619047619, 
    4.80952380952381, 4.80952380952381, 4.14285714285714, 4.28571428571429, 
    4.47619047619048, 3.83333333333333, 4.16666666666667, 4.23809523809524, 
    3.85714285714286, 3.61904761904762, 4.85714285714286, 4.5952380952381, 
    4.88095238095238, 3.78571428571429, 4.11904761904762, 4.21428571428571, 
    4.14285714285714, 4.11904761904762, 4.19047619047619, 3.5, 
    3.61904761904762, 4.28571428571429, 3.85714285714286, 4.4047619047619, 
    3.69047619047619, 4.23809523809524, 4.42857142857143, 3.83333333333333, 
    3.4047619047619, 3.5952380952381, 3.88095238095238, 3.83333333333333, 
    3.95238095238095, 4.5952380952381, 3.71428571428571, 4.78571428571429, 
    4, 4, 3.73809523809524, 3.47619047619048, 2.07142857142857, 
    3.9047619047619, 4.92857142857143, 4.4047619047619, 4.30952380952381, 
    4.4047619047619, 4.30952380952381, 4.21428571428571, 4.07142857142857, 
    3.5952380952381, 4.26190476190476, 4.30952380952381, 4, 4.45238095238095, 
    4.54761904761905, 3.95238095238095, 4.26190476190476, 4.23809523809524, 
    3.76190476190476, 4.85714285714286, 3.30952380952381, 4.02380952380952
    ), level = c("high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "high", 
    "low", "low", "low", "low", "high", "high", "low", "high", 
    "high", "low", "high", "low", "low", "low", "low", "high", 
    "high", "high", "high", "high", "low", "high", "low", "low", 
    "high", "high", "high", "high", "low", "high", "high", "high", 
    "low", "low", "low", "high", "high", "low", "low", "high", 
    "high", "low", "high", "high", "low", "high", "low", "low", 
    "high", "low", "high", "high", "high", "low", "high", "low", 
    "low", "high", "low", "low", "high", "low", "low", "low", 
    "high", "low", "low", "low", "high", "low", "low", "low", 
    "high", "high", "high", "low", "low", "low", "low", "high", 
    "low", "high", "high", "low", "high", "low", "low", "low", 
    "low", "high", "high", "high", "high", "low", "low", "low", 
    "high", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
    "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "low", 
    "low", "low", "low", "low", "high", "high", "low", "high", 
    "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "high", 
    "low", "high", "low", "low", "high", "high", "low", "high", 
    "low", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "low", "high", 
    "low", "high", "high", "high", "high", "high", "high", "low", 
    "high", "high", "low", "low", "high", "high", "high", "low", 
    "high", "high", "high", "high", "high", "low", "low", "high", 
    "low", "high", "low", "high", "high", "low", "low", "low", 
    "low", "low", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "low", 
    "low", "low", "low", "low", "high", "high", "high", "high", 
    "high", "high", "low", "low", "high", "high", "low", "high", 
    "high", "low", "high", "high", "low", "high", "low", "low"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -215L), class = "data.frame")


I'm unsure from your example what your groups are. However, if you simply want to filter for multiple groups you can use %in%:
filter(level %in% group)


Thank you @lmf0845. I have added the group in the data. The group that I want to include in the function is to enable calculation for high group, low group, and both groups.

This works. Thanks a lot.
